# Using JQuery to modify data written to document by functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Most of my html is data that is provided via a Jquery request. It is written to the page by inserting it into a "main" div like such:

```
$("#main").html(passedData);
}
```

The page works great, but now i'm having problems trying to add any javascript to that data that is written to the div.

Namely I have tables that are inserted into the div and I am trying to write scripts that hide certain cells when others are clicked. I've used http://jsfiddle.net/ to make sure that all of my JS is correct, but for some reason it seems like the JS functions don't see that data in the div and won't manipulate it.

Is there anything I'm missing? When writing data to a page like this do you have to do certain things to reference that data with javascript?

Comment: If you don't post the actual code that you're using, nobody can help you.

Comment: I am betting you are assigning the click events before the new table is added. BUT I can not verify this due to the fact you did not show an example with the problem.

Comment: You're both correct, thanks for the help. Sorry that I didn't include code, with the way that my site is setup that would have to be pulled from about 10 locations :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach event handlers to those  "future" elements like this:

```
$("#main").on("click", ".myelement", function(){
        // Do something
});
```

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, it would be a lot easier if you posted your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot without the actual code, but I'm almost certain the problem is that when your jQuery code is executed, the elements that were pulled in through AJAX didn't exist. Therefor, no events will be attached to them.

You should look into using [jQuery's .on() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Attach it to a parent element that exists when DOM-ready is fired, and you can manipulate any elements inside it that were pulled in dynamically.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was trying to figure out. It looks like I'll need to add these event handlers after the data has been written to the page.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any answers that helped you; and accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I actually just found a simple way of fixing my problem. At the end of the function that writes the data to the page, I added the event handlers, and they work correctly. Thanks for your help.